# How does the workflow with Haskell Stack work?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I don't get the point about Stack.

I used to write my Haskell code in my favourite environment, ran or compiled using GHC(i), and if necessary, installed packages using Cabal. Now, that apparently is not the way to go any more, but I don't understand how to work with Stack. So far, I have only understood that I need to write `stack exec ghci` instead `ghci` to start a repl.

Apart from that, the docs always talk about 'projects' for which I have to write some yaml files. But I probably don't have any project -- I just want to launch a GHCi repl and experiment a bit with my ideas. At the moment, this fails with the unability to get the packages that I want to work with installed.

How is working with Stack meant? Is there any explanation of their use cases? Where do I find my use case in there?

**Edit.** My confusion comes from the fact that I want to work with some software ([IHaskell](https://github.com/IHaskell/IHaskell)) whose installation guide explains the installation via stack. Assuming I already have a GHCi installed whose package base I maintain e.g. using Cabal. How would I have to set up `stack.yaml` to make stack use my global GHCi for that project?

Comment: Stack is meant to manage projects. If you're screwing around in a REPL, then you don't need it. Keep doing what you've always been doing. When you have a coherent, large goal you want to work toward, then you can start talking about making a project.

Comment: If you just want to mess around in ghci with some libraries available, try `cabal repl -b lib1 -b lib2` etc. That'll avoid cabal hell issues and give you access to whatever libraries. (Assuming there's some way to build your combination of targets for the current GHC version, anyway.)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo If course, if I had a large 'project' I would use a tool to manage all its dependencies, build process, tests... I guess that's what stack is for. But what I don't get is that not everything is a project.

Comment: Right, that's my point. If I want to mess around in Haskell, I'm going to use cabal and ghci. I'm going to use Stack when I want a big project. In the same vein, I'd never use Maven to mess around in Java. I'd just use javac and set my classpath directly. Maven is for big projects.

Comment: `stack` is like `conda` or `pipenv` for python. `GHC(i)` would be the python interpreter, and `cabal` would be `pip` (this is more true in older versions of `cabal`, the analogy doesn't fit perfectly here). `stack` It is meant to be a _project_ based tool. You create a project with dependencies, modules, etc... and `stack build` will create an isolated enviroment with all deps installed only within that env, and they cannot be access out of the environment.

Comment: @lsmor I see. I have extended my question to explain what I want to achieve and why I ended up wondering about stack.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that `stack` will use its own package base independent from `cabal`. AFAIK they can't be shared... hence, if you run `stack build` it'll download packages (including the compiler) on its own package database.

Nevertheless `stack` allows to use a system compiler (but not other libraries). To do so, in the `stack.yaml` you *must* have the following two lines

```
resolver: lts-XX.XX -- keep reading below
system-ghc: True
```

The version of the stackage snapshot can be found in: https://www.stackage.org/. Each snapshot works with a different version of the compiler. Be sure to use a  snapshot with the same compiler version you have in you system. If it happens your system ghc is greater than any `lts`, then you can set `allow-newer: true` in `stack.yaml`.

Now, if getting a different database from stack feels wrong to you, notice that you can build the project with `cabal` too, since `stack` at the end of the day spits out a `cabal` file. Probably, It wont work out of the box if you build with `cabal`. You can modify the cabal file to match exactly the version of the packages of the snapshot you are using

In summary:

- You can use your system-wide ghc
- you can *not* share libraries installed with cabal.
- you can use `cabal` to build the project, probably modifying the `ihaskell.cabal` file to match versions of the stackage's snapshot.